# Is a bad practice make variations on power's tracks width in pcb?

Tags: pcb-design

Its is about a circuit to source power and communicate with a car's key. I don't know exactly the current necessary, but I know that it is low, a few mA. The voltages are 5.5V and 3.3V.
The frequency of the signals are not high , a few units of KHz, something near 10kHz.

I would like to know if variation on tracks's width like the signalized in red on the figure below are very problematic. The signalized on the figure are GND, and VCC.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I would like to know if variation on tracks's width like the signalized in red on the figure below are very problematic.

At 10 kHz (or probably even 10 MHz), the indicated trace width variations are not significant.

It's pretty common to have this kind of feature in a design. Particularly when high currents are involved you might want the trace as wide as possible to minimize voltage drop, but need to narrow it down in certain areas to fit other traces or components. In a DC or low-frequency AC power track this will cause no problem as long as the narrow section is short (you could calculate the actual resistance effect and be sure it doesn't exceed your requirements).

Answer (score 1):

I think the significance of trace length and geometry matters for higher frequencies where intereference from reflections can be critical. I think sub < 1 MHz designs shoud be still okay.

Comment: This is a fair answer but is there anything to provide any proof? i.e. standard specifications that talk about track widths?

Comment: I think the OP is worried about cross-talk which happens at almost all frequencies. However, my knowledege comes from reading High Speed Design guidelines and iterating through multiple designs.

Answer (score 1):

If u are using it for audio no problem there, right, if u wanna design for RF, I'd avoid your drawing work, I'd use soft-round corners